# Populate input and textarea with angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I make a ToDo list in angularJS to testing local storage.

In my mainController I have it:

```
$scope.saved = localStorage.getItem('todos');
$scope.todos = (localStorage.getItem('todos')!==null) ? JSON.parse($scope.saved) : [  ];
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify($scope.todos))

var oldTodos;

$scope.addLocalStorage = function() {
    $scope.todos.push({
        text: $scope.todoText,
        content: $scope.todoContent,
        done: false
    });

    $scope.todoText = ''; //clear the input after adding
    $scope.todoContent = ''; //clear the input after adding
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify($scope.todos));

    console.log('Adicionado ao local storage com sucesso!');
    window.location = '#/list';
};

$scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo){
        count+= todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
};

$scope.removeLocalStorage = function() {
    oldTodos = $scope.todos;
    $scope.todos = [];

    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo){
        if (!todo.done)
            $scope.todos.push(todo);
        console.log('Removido do local storage com sucesso!');
    });

    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify($scope.todos));
};

$scope.getDataLocalStorage = function() {
    var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1].innerHTML;
    console.log('obj: ' + obj);

    window.location = '#/editcard';
}
```

In my edit-card.html file I have it:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <form>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="edit_title" type="text" ng-model="todoText" class="validate done-{{ todo.done }}">
            <label for="edit_title">Title</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea id="edit_content" type="text" ng-model="todoContent" class="materialize-textarea" ng-model="todo.done">{{ todo.content }}</textarea>
          <label for="edit_content">Content</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="right">
                <button class="waves-effect light-green darken-4 btn" type="submit" value="submit" href="/#/list"> Salvar Offline </button>
                <button class="waves-effect light-green darken-4 btn" type="submit" value="submit" href="/#/list"> Enviar </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

in my list.html a have it:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="items_on_card" class="card grey lighten-4" ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" ng-model="todo.done" id="item-{{todo}}">
        <label for="item-{{todo}}" class="done-{{ todo.done }}">{{ todo.text }}</label>
        <i ng-click="getDataLocalStorage()">
            <p id="item-description" ng-model="todo.done">{{ todo.content }}</p>
        </i>
    </div>

    <div align="right">
        <span>{{ remaining() }} de {{ todos.length }} restante</span><br><br>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light light-green darken-4 btn" type="button" href="/#/addnew">Novo</a>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light red darken-2 btn" type="button" ng-click="removeLocalStorage()">Excluir</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My function `getDataLocalStorage` doesn't work

I have an error :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at ChildScope.$scope.getDataLocalStorage`

What I need to do is, after add a new item in ToDo I can edit it later and update with a new data, but I would like to show in input tag and textarea tag the current data to be edited.

Does anyone know to do it?

Comment: You don't have `p` tag in your HTML. Please post a working copy. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited, I forgot to put the other `html` file

Comment: Try to debug the application. put a `debugger` statement and try what `document.getElementsByTagName('p')` returning.

Comment: The error occurred because I returned the second element in array, but I don't had the item, thank you!

Comment: But I don't got to show the current data when I select the ToDo item

Answer (score 1):

var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1].innerHTML;
You are referencing the list of p elements, but there are no p elements in the document.